# Can MR16 12V DC LED bulbs be used on 12V AC power?

Tags: electrical

I have DC MR16 bulbs. Is it safe to use them on my AC track lighting? Will that work?

Comment: Why do you think your bulbs are DC?  MR16 systems were originally 12V halogen bulbs driven with 12V AC from a transformer.  All the LED MR16s that I have seen are plug-in replacements.

Comment: Looks like if you have them it is worth a try they will work or kinda work and die. I ordered some for equipment not long ago and they were dc as they flashed and smoked within a few seconds, since I had 6 of them I put a diode in line and that worked I can’t see any flicker.